# Second Roscore cannot run even though different ROS_MASTER_URI is set

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run two ROS masters on one computer, because I need to run two Gazebo simulations and control the robot in both of them, and it seems, that the package, that provides controllers for robot simulation (gazebo_ros_control) can only launch one node, so when I launch the second simulation on the same ROS core, the controllers of the first simulation stops.

So I launch a roscore in standard ROS_MASTER_URI on one terminal and then attempt to run a ROS core in another terminal, where different ROS_MASTER_URI is set. But it results into an error, claiming that the ROS core can't be launched, because it is already running at the standard ROS_MASTER_URI.
I think it should be possible to run two ROS cores on one computer just like this, so what am I missing?

Terminal 1:

```
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
$ roscore
```

output:

```
started roslaunch server http://linux-Precision-T1650:44253/
ros_comm version 1.12.14


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [27762]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://linux-Precision-T1650:11311/

setting /run_id to f6eefa2c-2565-11e9-b08b-b8ca3aa30f44
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [27776]
started core service [/rosout]
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11312
$ roscore
```

output:

```
started roslaunch server http://linux-Precision-T1650:45643/
ros_comm version 1.12.14


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES

roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://linux-Precision-T1650:11311/
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314368/second-roscore-cannot-run-even-though-different-ros_master_uri-is-set/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:\

> it seems, that the package, that provides controllers for robot simulation (gazebo_ros_control) can only launch one node, so when I launch the second simulation on the same ROS core, the controllers of the first simulation stops.

It is actually possible to use multiple `ros_control` ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:
.. controlled robots in a single Gazebo instance.

I can't find the relevant docs/Q&As right now, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable should be used if you want to specify what's the uri of the master such that other nodes can find it.

If you want to run more than one `roscore` on the same machine you have to use the `-p` option to specify a different port.

TERMINAL1

```
roscore
```

TERMINAL 2

```
roscore -p <PORT_NUMBER>
```

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of https://answers.ros.org/question/57539/how-to-run-multiple-roscoremaster-in-a-single-machine/

Use `roscore -p 11312` in the second terminal, you don't need to tweak the `ROS_MASTER_URI` variable.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1